# Error when using 'find_all_by_'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, findall, findby

I get an error while using `find_all_by_`

```
controller
@books = Book.find_by_author_id(4)

View
<%= @books.name %>
```

This works. But when I replace `find_by_` with `find_all_by_` I get this error

```
undefined method `name'
```

I want to use `find_all_by_` to fetch all the books corresponding to `author_id=4`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Controller
@books = Book.find_all_by_author_id(4)

View
<%= @books.map(&:name).join(', ') %>
```

you are getting an `Array` of records. And `Array` does not have the `name` method.